# ChromeDriver - Timeout when trying to print page with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need to save a page as a PDF but I'm having issues. I'm using ChromeDriver and just using google as an example (since my app requires logging in) I navigate to the page (google.com). Then execute window.print() in javascript to get the print window to come up. Chrome opens the print preview page and I get the src of the iframe showing the pdf so I can pull the pdf from the url.

My issue is that at the point I execute the javascript it opens the print preview but execution stops there. It's like ChromeDriver is waiting for the page to say it's finished but the message never comes so I recieve a WebDriverException saying it timed out.

The weird thing is this used to work up until yesterday when I got a bunch of windows updates and updated a bunch of programs including Chrome.

So does anyone have any idea how to make this work again?

I'm using Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS is Windows 10
ChromeDriver version is 2.33.0
Selenium WebDriver is 3.7.0

Here's the error:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:12277/session/f8ac647c64a7e61a5d84e4ed9daa8c7c/execute timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The operation has timed out.
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScriptCommand(String script, String commandName, Object[] args)
>      at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.ExecuteScript(String script, Object[] args)
>      at Err.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Temp\Err\Err\Program.cs:line 34

Here's the code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        try
        {

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("window.print();"); //this is the line that throws the error
        }
        catch (WebDriverException ex)
        {
            //just eat the error here since it's done opening the pdf viewer
        }


        //cannot execute the line below because the driver is dead in the water at this point - anything I try to do with it just times out...
        var q = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("descendant::input[@class = 'q']"));
    }
```

Comment: Try with an asynchronous call: `js.ExecuteScript("setTimeout(window.print, 5);");`

Comment: @FlorentB.thanks, I'll try that on Monday when I'm back in the office and report back my results.

Comment: @FlorentB. that did the trick but I don't understand how. Could you explain how that resolved the issue?

Comment: The print dialog locks the main thread and prevents the browser from responding to the driver, which leads to the timeout you are experiencing.